# Add Data to MongoDB Models At Different Times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a pretty good understanding of mongdoDB with mongoose, but this one aspect of it has been confusing me for a while now. I have a user.js model with a username, password, etc (all the basic user stuff). This data is added when a user registers for an account. But each user also has more data linked to it that IS NOT created or added at the time of registering.

This is my model:

```
// User Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({

    // PERSONAL USER INFO
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },

    // INSTAGRAM ACCOUNT INFORMATION
    ig_username: {
        type: String
    },
    ig_password: {
        type: String
    },
    story_price: {
        type: Number
    },
    fullpost_price: {
        type: Number
    },
    halfpost_price: {
        type: Number
    },
    leads: [{
        title: { type: String }
    }]
});

// EXPORTS
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

All the field except "leads" are created at the time of registering. But I want to fill the Leads field using another form. I've tried the .update(), .save(), $set, $push, and all kinds of methods, but I cannot get it to work.

Most solutions that I have found use `var user = new User({...})` to create a new user and then use `.save()` after adding the additional data. But this seems wrong since the user has already been created and I am just trying to add data to an additional field.

I think I'm just glossing over something basic, but if there is a way to do this I would be glad to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Something like `User.update({username:some user},{$push:{leads:new lead}})`

Comment: @Veeram I've tried that method before but when I check the user in the mongo shell it does not create the "leads" document". The user just looks the exact same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a sub-schema for leads

```
// Create a sub-schema for leads
const leadsSubSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
});

// Create a schema for user
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },

  // ...

  leads: [leadsSubSchema]
});

// EXPORTS
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

---

Then for the update

```
User.update({
  _id: user_id,
}, {
  $push: {
    leads: lead_to_add,
  },
});
```